# How to get specific information from Firestore when specific row is tapped

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

**The goal here is to get specific information from Firebase Firestore when tapping on a specific row from Table View in Xcode.** I have already found a way to store the data into a Table View:

```
func loadData() {
        FirebaseFirestore.root.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    for document in snapshot.documents {

                        let data = document.data()
                        let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
                        let phone = data["phone"] as? String ?? ""

                        let newPerson = Person(name: name, email: email, phone: phone)
                        self.people.append(newPerson)
                        print (self.people)

                        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.people.count - 1, section: 0)

                        self.table.beginUpdates()
                        self.table.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
                        self.table.endUpdates()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And when running, this shows up:

[image]

When I tap row 1, for example, I want to segue into another view that displays the name, email, phone for each specific row. Is this possible? And if so, how would I do this?

**------------------------------**

So far, I thought of adding another variable to each row, but not displaying on the row. Since in Firebase, the document id is the email, I can set the var email to every row, and use getDocument() to retrieve the document by email, the document id.

All I've done was use the variable email to try to use getDocument on the didSelectRowAt function.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let tappedUser = FirebaseFirestore.root.collection("users").document(email)

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPersonDesc", sender: nil)
    }
```

But this doesn't work. I don't think I can use the email var since it gives an error for *Person.email*, and just *email*.

Any help would be appreciated.

**-------------------------------**

***Entire code block if anyone needs it (updated to what I've tried):***

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

struct Person {
    let name, phone, email: String
}

class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var phone: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UILabel!
}

class PeopleViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    var people = [Person]()
    private var document: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.table.delegate = self
        self.table.dataSource = self

        loadData()

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return self.people.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let person = people[indexPath.row]
        let cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell

        cell.name.text = person.name
        cell.phone.text = person.phone
        cell.email.text = person.email

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let tappedUser = FirebaseFirestore.root.collection("users").document(Person.email)//Error here

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPersonDesc", sender: nil)
    }

    func loadData() {
        FirebaseFirestore.root.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    for document in snapshot.documents {

                        let data = document.data()
                        let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let phone = data["phone"] as? String ?? ""
                        let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""

                        let newPerson = Person(name: name, phone: phone, email: email)
                        self.people.append(newPerson)
                        print (self.people)

                        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.people.count - 1, section: 0)

                        self.table.beginUpdates()
                        self.table.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
                        self.table.endUpdates()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What’s the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: @Daniel, Oh sorry, I haven't edited the question with what I tried yet, I'll edit it now.

Comment: Check out the answer below.

Comment: when the user tapped send that row email to the next screen. On the next Screen query database using the email and get all the data that you require.

Comment: @JawadAhmed, How will I send 'email' to the next screen? Once I get that, I think I can finish the rest.

Comment: Get the email on user tap and use this method https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/

Answer (score 0):

Hey this actually isn't that difficult fortunately.  All you need to do is something like this:

```
//Create a custom UIViewController class which has a property of type Person.
class CustomViewController : UIViewController {    
    var person: Person?
    // You'll need to set this up using a .xib file
    weak var customView:CustomView?     
}

class UsersViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {    
    var person:[Person]?

    //This method will be executed every time the user clicks on the row. Make sure that your current class adopts the UITableViewDelegate protocol.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Insert your functionality to get the correct person and set the person property in the new custom view controller.
        let viewController = CustomViewController()
        viewController.person = self.person?[indexPath.row]
        // Display the new custom view controller.
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. Create a custom UIViewController class which has a property of type Person.
2. This method - func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) - will be executed every time the user clicks on the row.  ***Make sure that your current class adopts the UITableViewDelegate protocol.***
3. Within the didSelectRow function, insert your functionality to get the correct person and set the person property in the new custom view controller.
4. Display the new custom view controller.

***You will need to make sure that you set up the view of the view controller to display the data in the person object.  Check out this [video](https://medium.com/@umairhassanbaig/ios-swift-creating-a-custom-view-with-xib-ace878cd41c5) if you need to know how to do that.***

If you want any clarification of this just let me know!

Edit:

There are multiple ways to do this.  Firebase has a functionality to watch a document and if there are changes to the document server-side than you can apply those changes in the app.  Check it out [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

I would probably look into using something like that.

Or you can fetch the data within the didSelectRow and than once the data is retrieved show the new view controller.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but do I use the storyboard or use the xib file? I'm a little confused. Also, I hoped to see how I would pull the data for when a row is tapped. For example when I tapped on the first row, I would get the extra data from Firestore for the first row and input it onto another view. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: In the prepareForSegue method set the person object on the segue.destinationViewController object. Then in the viewDidLoad method you can run your code to get the extra data from Firebase. But what extra data are you needing from Firebase? Once I get that information I can provide a more detailed explanation

Comment: I'm creating an app based off of your location, so I would need the zip code. Then, when I tap on a row, it would display name, email, phone, and zip code. Also, just as a side question, do you know how to transform the email var to a public var?

Comment: A simple clarification might solve this problem, i.e. do you have all the data at the first table view or just the list of zip codes? In any case, this quick start guide from apple will help you solve your problem (the part about passing data between viewcontrollers) https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1

Comment: @existingperson I just updated my answer, maybe it will help. Also, to make the email var public you need to move it's declaration outside of the closure and to the class level.  Maybe this article can help you out. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html Or you might want to do a search for variables in Swift on Google.